# Содержимое БД в формате json

Tags: joomla, php, json, mysql

Имеется сайт на движке Joomla и для него необходимо написать приложение под Android.
Планируется брать данные из БД сайта.
Подскажите, как лучше реализовать эту задачу (получить данные из БД по запросу в формате json)?

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так, например:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT
    ("[",
        GROUP_CONCAT
        (
            CONCAT('{"field_one":"', field_one, '"'),
            CONCAT(',"field_two":"', field_two, '"}')
        )
     ,"]"
    ) 
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: плюсую по традиции